# Is it possible to change the way website is rendered with my own browser?

Tags: c#, php, html, css, visual-studio-2010

I'm looking to make a mod manager for the Indie game Kerbal Space Program and in order to do this i'm planning on rendering a cut-down version of their mod website Kerbal Spaceport in a built in browser in a windows application.

Is it possible to alter the way the website is rendered client-side while retaining the original underlying links? I plan on using Visual C# to code the windows application, but i also have a decent understanding of PHP and most of the other common web development languages aside from ASP. Essentially i want to change the CSS of the website so that i can display elements of the website in a non-graphical, list format.

How difficult would this be for someone who has about 2 years experience in programming? I'm fairly capable with OO programming languages and have a strong understanding of HTML, CSS, JavaScript, with a dash of PHP.

Comment: You do understand that the possible answers to your question are yes and no?

Comment: @Reniuz Well the only answer is yes if you think about it, because if you make your own browser you can make anything look like anything!

Comment: It's even worse. If you want to "display elements of the website in a non-graphical, list format", you won't need to write a browser of your own. Just press Ctrl+U.

Answer (score 0):

this can pretty much be done in most web browsers. In Chrome if you press ctrl + Shift + i 
this brings up a window, here is the HTML for the current webpage. from this window you are free to edit the webpage to your liking. bearing in mind that any changes will only be made client side and as soon as you refresh the page, it will request the page again from the server unchanged.